# Loading an int and an encrypted String from txt file

Tags: java, file, inputstream, fileinputstream

I am working on the password login portion of a class project. Nothing fancy. User, or role will be an int and password is a String. I am just using a simple encryption for now. The problem I am having is while reading the file I am getting an input mismatch. I have done something similar in the past that required me to read ints and Strings and did not have any problems. But I just cannot figure out what is going wrong in this case. Any help as to why I am getting this error would be greatly appreciated. I am using `while(inputStream.hasNextLine())` then read the `int` and then the `String` I have tried `hasNextInt` and `hasNext` and keep getting the same error.

```
public void readFile(){
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new Scanner (new FileInputStream("login.txt"));
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(inputStream != null){
    while (inputStream.hasNextLine()){
        int luser = inputStream.nextInt();
        String lpass = inputStream.nextLine();
        newFile[count] = new accessNode(luser, lpass);
        count ++;
    }
    inputStream.close();
    }    
}
```

Comment: You need to post the actual error you're getting to get good help - i,e, the actual error message showing which line is failing and the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading it as a String and converting the string to an int

```
while (inputStream.hasNextLine()) {

    Integer luser = Integer.parseInt(inputStream.nextLine());
    String lpass = inputStream.nextLine();
    newFile[count] = new accessNode(luser, lpass);
    count++;
}
```

But you need to make sure your file has your data in the exact format as below

```
12342
password
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without knowing what error it is that you are getting, but my guess is that it is because you are not reading the entire file.

Your file probably looks like this:

```
1\r\n
password\r\n
```

When you call nextInt() it reads the int, but doesn't advance past the first \r\n so when you call nextLine() it reads to the end of the line so all you get is \r\n. You need to read past the first \r\n and then read the password.

Try

```
int luser = inputStream.nextInt();
inputStream.nextLine();
String lpass = inputStream.nextLine();
newFile[count] = new accessNode(luser, lpass);
```